# How to link from docker-compose to Amazon RDS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml looks something like this:

```
django:
  build: .
  user: django
  links:
    # LINK TO AMAZON RDS?
  command: /gunicorn.sh
  env_file: config/settings/.env

nginx:
  build: ./compose/nginx
  links:
    - django
  ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
```

How do I link the django container to the Amazon RDS, which has an url like: `example.blahblahblah.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In that case, you don't have to define a "link"; the database service is already running, so all you need to do, is configure your django app to connect to that host.

I don't have experience with django, but based on the [example in the docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database), it would look something like;

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'example.blahblahblah.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```